# how to unblock the password of sudo of the user in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am the only user of Linux (Ubuntu) - admin (sudo user).

I have  blocked himself as follows:

```
 $ sudo passwd -l admin
```

**Help me to unblock yourself.**

I (user admin) can't unlock the password:

```
  $ ssh admin@remotehost "sudo passwd -u admin"
  sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

  $ ssh -t admin@remotehost "sudo passwd -u admin"
  [sudo] password for admin: 
  Sorry, try again.
  [sudo] password for admin: 
  Sorry, try again.
  [sudo] password for admin: 
  sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
  Connection to remotehost closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page of `passwd`, when you specify option `-l`, the `/etc/shadow` file is updated.

```
-l, --lock
       Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a
       password by changing it to a value which matches no possible
       encrypted value (it adds a ´!´ at the beginning of the password).

       Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still
       be able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH
       key). To disable the account, administrators should use usermod
       --expiredate 1 (this set the account's expire date to Jan 2,
       1970).

       Users with a locked password are not allowed to change their
       password.
```

As we can read it, users with a locked password are not allowed to update their password. Another user have to update the `/etc/shadow` file to unlock the account.

In your case, you need a physical access to your server, then you have to boot on a live cd/usb linux and edit `/etc/shadow` file to remove the `!` character. If you don't have such an access, contact your provided to check if some recovery options exist (web tty, backup, humain intervention, etc.)

Comment: More likely the `/etc/shadow` file nowadays

Comment: Indeed, thx :)
     `/etc/passwd` : User account information.
     `/etc/shadow` : Secure user account information.

Comment: @FaikStack you need to be root to edit the file and you can't become root anymore because you locked the only way to do that... If you don't have physical access to the server it all depends on what kind of server this is and what recovery options the provider offers.

Comment: Thanks, i have loaded (IPMI) with use of GRUB and I have removed "!". Unfortunately yet there are no rights to plus to the answer.